# ResourceDictionary + StaticResource alternative for pure System.XAML, no PresentationFramework

Tags: .net

I would like to enjoy the `ResourceDictionary` + `StaticResource` functionality, but without the need to load PresentationFramework - pure System.Xaml.

I managed, quite easily, to define the Resources property as a dictionary, but I need a way to reference the items there, i.e. I need something like `StaticResource`. I looked at it with Reflector and it seems to depend on a stuff in WindowsBase and PresentationFramework.

I was wondering if there is another way, without gliding into PresentationFramework. I also understand, that I can to copy-paste all the relevant code from PresentationFramework leaving only the bare minimum to support the needed functionality - this is my last resort.

Here is what I have until now:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Xaml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  [ContentProperty("Items")]
  public class XamlDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
  {
    public ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> Items
    {
      get { return this; }
    }
  }

  public class A
  {
    private XamlDictionary<string, int> m_resources;
    public XamlDictionary<string, int> Resources 
    {
      get
      {
        if (m_resources == null)
        {
          m_resources = new XamlDictionary<string, int>();
        }
        return m_resources;
      }
      set { m_resources = value; }
    }
    public int Value { get; set; }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var a = (A)XamlServices.Load("A.xaml");
    }
  }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<l:A xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
     xmlns:l="clr-namespace:ConsoleApplication1;assembly=ConsoleApplication1"
     Value="15">
  <l:A.Resources>
    <sys:Int32 x:Key="ssss">10</sys:Int32>
  </l:A.Resources>
</l:A>
```

So far so good, everything is fine. Now I wish to change the Xaml so that `A.Value` reference the `A.Resources["ssss"]` value and here is where I need the `StaticResource` alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a "StaticResourceExtention" to be part of the markup =)